# Can't connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have an instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 on my local machine, and today, when I try to connect via Management Studio (as I used to do with no errors, using Windows Authentication), I get the following error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Any sugestions?

Comment: Verify that the Sql Server service started.

Comment: Follow the links : http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error

Comment: @HamletHakobyan How I verify this?

Comment: @KhurramAli I not found this: SQL Server Surface Area Configuration, the guide talks about SQL Server 2005, maybe in 2008 have a different name?

Comment: @DaniloSilva : Ok Try This 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Comment: @DaniloSilva : To Verify Sql Server Service started :
go to Windows Service or type services.msc in run and check you sql service is started or not

Comment: @HamletHakobyan The service was stoped, I started the service and now its working. Thanks.

Comment: @KhurramAli I started the service and now its working. Thanks!